# Can't find my android smartphone with eclipse/adb

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I can't get eclipse / adb to find my htc desire x.
I tried about everything, google usb drivers, htc sync, etc.
I got usb debugging enabled but since i got android 4.1.1 i can't change the usb connection to "charge only", seems like it's supposed to do that on itself.
restarted pc / htc, tried adb kill-server etc nothing seems to work.

anyone an idea what the reason could be?

Comment: Is your sdk up to date?

Comment: @AJak - ADB started requiring whitelist authentication (and an SDK recent enough to support that) in Android 4.2.2, so while that was a good suggestion it doesn't seem likely to be the issue for a 4.1.1 device unless the vendor cherry-picked this change.

Comment: This may be unnecessary, but are you absolutely sure you still have USB debugging enabled?  Do you have a `Developer Options` settings menu?  If not you will need to go into `About Phone` and tap the build number 6 or 7 times to make this hidden menu appear, then you can enable USB debugging.  Also make sure your drivers are keyed to the VID of your phone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=pl) and type

```
ps | grep adb
```

If you will not get any output, your ROM doesn't not support debugging.

Comment: u0_a25@android:/ $ ps | grep adb /system/bin/sh: grep: not found [1] + Stopped (signal) ps | Done (127) grep adb 127|u0_a25@android:/ $ [1] + Broken pipe ps | Done (127) grep adb                          does this mean it doesnt support debugging?

Comment: no, it means that you don't have grep tool, so type `ps > /sdcard/ps.txt` then copy file `ps.txt` from your sd card to computer and search in that file `adb` (or paste this file here)

Comment: found this line: shell     2401  1     3532   220   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd

Comment: So it seems everything is ok with phone. Can you try on different computer?

Comment: well ok. should have tried that earlier. my laptop actually finds it. thank you for your help^^ u don't know by any chance any possibility my pc doesnt find it?

Comment: This is a poor recommendation as **most official android builds do not have `grep`**

Comment: Most Android developers have installed BusyBox. And see my comments, then you know what to do if you don't have grep.

Comment: @sebastianruland What OS are you using at all?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of restarting the PC,give a try to restart your cell.I had ran into same issue with my Samsung galaxy Y.and It was solved by restarting my cell.